# Tempo real com PHP

Tags: php, node.js, websocket

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e logo terei de iniciar a parte de interações em tempo real (para notificações e chat). Estou utilizando `jQuery`, `PHP` e `MySQL` até o momento e pretendo continuar com essas tecnologias.

Já vi sobre `long-polling` porém li que não é uma boa prática, visto que, várias requisições seriam feitas ao servidor e, dependendo do número de acessos o mesmo poderia sobrecarregar. Li também sobre `WebSockets` porém ainda não consegui entender como utilizar, e gostaria de saber também seu suporte a navegadores. Pesquisando sobre, encontrei o [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/), mas o que seria? Um "framework" para auxiliar na utilização de `WebSockets`? Outra opção da qual tive conhecimento é do famoso `Node.js` porém teria como utilizá-lo separadamente somente para a parte das notificações/chat? Se sim, como faria essa "integração/mistura" entre `PHP` e `Node.js`?

De qualquer forma, mesmo sem ter experiência alguma com tais assuntos (`WebSockets`/`Node.js`) gostaria de utilizar `WebSockets` para não ter que envolver `Node.js` e continuar utilizando das tecnologias atuais do projeto.

Comment: Talvez este tutorial possa te ajudar:
http://www.davidchc.com.br/video-aula/php/criando-um-chat-utilizando-jquery-e-php/

Comment: Infelizmente esse tutorial não serve, visto que esse chat não é em tempo real, o jQuery apenas simula isso de certa forma. Tal forma da qual eu exatamente não quero fazer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WebSocket é um protocolo de comunicação bidirecional [compatível com todos os navegadores atuais](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets). É ideal para comunicações persistentes entre aplicativo-servidor, o que possibilita que notificações sejam enviadas/recebidas em tempo real.

É possível desenvolver uma solução utilizando PHP. O recomendado seria mesmo recorrer a algum framework como o [**Ratchet**](http://socketo.me/), pois implementar uma solução com WebSocket do zero é uma tarefa bem complexa.

Note que as conexões concorrentes no Apache [são muito inferiores](http://zgadzaj.com/benchmarking-nodejs-basic-performance-tests-against-apache-php) às conexões concorrentes do node.js. Isso pode ser mitigado de diversas maneiras, o nginx tipicamente possui mais conexões concorrentes e pode ser mais adequado para isso.

### node.js

Outra alternativa mais popular que o Ratchet/PHP para esse tipo de tarefa seria o node.js, usado no Microsoft Office, Yammer, Zendesk, Trello, em hackathons e pequenas startups. E sim, é possível, normal e muito comum usar PHP/Python/Ruby/ASP e node juntos. Começar a usar node.js não tem nada de muito novo se você já for desenvolvedor front-end, pois a linguagem também é JavaScript. A diferença é que com você usará JavaScript no lado do servidor.

Se você optar pelo node.js, não esqueça de dar uma olhada na biblioteca [socket.io](http://socket.io/). Funciona em todos os navegadores, até mesmo os mesmo os antigos que nem suportam WebSocket (<= IE 9). Isso se deve a um engenhoso mecanismo de fallbacks: ele tenta usar `WebSocket`, se não estiver disponível, parte para o `Flash Socket`, em seguida `AJAX`, `long-polling`, `AJAX multipart streaming`, `IFrame`, e por fim `JSONP polling`. Todos esses seis mecanismos funcionam com o mesmo código que você escrever (por isso compensa tanto usar uma biblioteca ao invés de implementar WebSocket na mão).

[Esse demo de chat](http://socket.io/demos/chat/) é usado na documentação. A aplicação no servidor tem apenas 79 linhas de código, bastante simples.

Lembre-se que você não **precisa** do node.js e introduzir outra plataforma na estrutura da sua aplicação adiciona um nível maior de complexidade (arquitetura monolítica x [microsserviços](https://www.thoughtworks.com/pt/insights/blog/microservices-nutshell)). O Ratchet é perfeitamente [equiparável ao socket.io no benchmark de desempenho](https://www.cargomedia.ch/2012/11/05/Benchmarking-WebSocket-Servers.html). Mas como o node.js está crescendo e o PHP desaparecendo, pode ser uma boa oportunidade implementar pequenas funcionalidades em node.js para aprender essa tecnologia.

Comment: Então, @rodorgas, eu já tenho um leve conhecimento sobre Node.js e possuo um livro do qual estou acompanhando para poder me aprofundar mais... Acontece que minha dúvida mesmo era em relação a "mistura" das linguagens e isso ainda me deixa confuso. Como eu faria essa "integração" de Node.js com PHP? Estou totalmente perdido e preciso desenvolver esse sistema...

Comment: O ideal seria eu reescrever totalmente minha aplicação em Node.js, porém como não possuo tanto conhecimento nem tempo disponível não poderei fazer isso. Caso haja retorno aí sim reprogramarei totalmente em Node.js. Por enquanto preciso de uma solução rápida e eficaz para notificações/chat...

Comment: @Igor Você deu uma olhada no demo do chat? Não é necessário reescrever a aplicação em node, pois ele é bom só pra esse tipo de coisa específica. Se você seguir o [tutorial básico](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/), vai entender melhor o processo. O PHP não fica integrado, o node roda em um servidor separado em uma porta separada. É tudo bem segmentado de modo que um praticamente independe do outro.

Comment: olhei sim, inclusive desenvolvi algumas coisas para testes tempos atrás. Mas, por exemplo, como eu poderia integrar um "chat geral" como o do exemplo em meu sistema que está em PHP? Como eu iria integrar esse chat em meu sistema?

Comment: @Igor A quais aspectos da integração você se refere? "Integrar" é tão genérico quanto "programar", a pergunta me soa tão hermética quanto "como vou programar?" Vou tentar responder: cria-se uma interface que o seu PHP provavelmente está gerando. A saída desse PHP deve ser um HTML tal que contenha um JS que te conecte, através do socket.io, no node.js que tá rodando em outra porta no seu servidor. A respeito dos detalhes de "como" isso se dará, tenho várias sugestões, mas na verdade depende muito do seu projeto.

Comment: Entendi, @rodorgas... No momento vou dar uma improvisada com jQuery e PHP mesmo, caso dê o mínimo retorno significativo vou de Node.js! Obrigado!