# É possível construir aplicações realtime usando servidores de hospedagem "normais"?

Tags: php, websocket, hospedagem

Bom, eu estou criando um mini-fórum, e cheguei a conclusão de que a melhor forma de construir esse fórum é usando aplicações real time. Porém, por enquanto, eu hospedo meu site em um servidor gratuito (como o hostinger), e até agora eu só ouvi falar no Node.js com web Socket para criar esse tipo de aplicação, e pelo que eu pude perceber, ele não funciona da forma convencional (antes eu simplesmente programava no localhost com o Xampp, e se funcionasse eu upava para o servidor usando o FileZilla e via a modificação dando um f5 no site. Mas aparentemente o node.js só funciona com servidores VPS. Então, há alguma forma de fazer um site realtime sem um servidor VPS?

Estou usando PHP, Mysql e JQuery atualmente.

Comment: Defina realtime. No contexto da pergunta, não vi nada que pudesse ter relação com o termo.

Comment: realtime como o chat do facebook.

Comment: Se fala de atualizar as coisas sem refresh, já tem muitas perguntas resolvendo isso no site. De fato, não tem nada a ver com realtime.

Comment: Sim, eu sei disso, mas a maioria das respostas é usando o ajax para atualizar a página de tempos em tempos. Só que quando eu faço isso, ele retorna o conteúdo tooodo, mesmo que não tenha nenhuma modificação nele (como uma nova mensagem no chat), ele traz todas as mensagens a cada segundo, e não só as novas a cada segundo. O webSocket resolve esse problema, mas ele só funciona com servidores VPS, então a minha dúvida é como fazer isso funcionar em um servidor de hospedagem comum.

Comment: Tem respostas sobre **long polling** e **websockets** também, pesquise sobre esses termos. Veja uma pergunta que é muito similar à sua: **[Tempo real com PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64234/70)**

Comment: websocket não é "realtime", na verdade isso é relativo, qualquer coisa pode ser "realtime", como ajax. O que você deseja é poder usar **websockets** com PHP. Sim é possível escrever um socket como PHP, mas ele *irá rodar independente do Apache* (xampp) e também irá gerar uma porta "exclusiva", agora rodar isto no servidor de produção vai depender se eles tem suporte, já que é "separado", neste caso só entrando em contato com o revendedor.

Comment: O problema do long pooling é que ele consome muito do servidor, e como eu pretendo muitas funções (que utilizariam long pooling), certamente iria demandar um processamento do servidor muito grande, e isso se tornaria um problema, pois eu ainda não pretendo gastar dinheiro para manter um servidor maior, sem contar que talvez nem o servidor maior dê conta de tanta requisição.

Comment: E @GuilhermeNascimento é justamente essa a minha dúvida: Se tem como eu fazer algo semelhante ao webSockets na mesma porta que o servidor de produção. Ou fazer algo que funcione junto com o xampp, sem precisar abrir uma porta especifica para isso.

Comment: Em relação à pergunta, a resposta é que ajax funciona em praticamente qualquer servidor, long polling e websockets dependem da hospedagem oferecer, o primeiro por causa do tempo de execução e o 2o por ser recurso especifico. E para saber isso, só consultando cada um deles. Não vejo muito como fugir disso.

Comment: O termo é dos mais mal usados que eu já vi. Eu vim quente porque eu tinha uma resposta boa, mas o assunto não tinha nada de tempo real.

Comment: @kyro23 não tem como fazer na mesma porta, ela esta ocupada pelo Apache, o servidor é o Apache e não o PHP, por isto tem que ter uma porta separada, e para conseguir rodar o socket no servidor vai só depender da hospedagem, na verdade tenho quase certeza que várias empresas de "hospedagem" tem serviços "extras" que podem ser contratados, basta solicitar ao setor de vendas se eles possuem isto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Então, esse serviço "extra" que você se refere, é justamente o VPS que eu falei, eu preciso que ele rode no servidor comum. Há algum framework ou algo que faça algo semelhante ao que o webSocket faz e não utilize portas diferentes?

Comment: @kyro23 é como eu disse antes, não tem como rodar, a porta já esta ocupada pelo Apache, o PHP não é o servidor em hospedagens HTTP comum, o servidor é o Apache, um framework PHP não irá resolver.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Entendi. Então eu vou testar com long pooling e com web sockets e ver qual é o melhor pra minha aplicação. Obrigado :)

Comment: @kyro23 long-poll pode até "resolver", mas eu acho uma técnica sombria, trabalhosa e que em um fluxo de muitos acessos não parece resolver nada, pelo contrário, pode até piorar se comparado a uma requisição normal.