# SetTimeOut e tráfego do servidor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com uma dúvida. Estou implementando o `setTimeOut()` em uma aplicação de comentários, onde a cada 3 segundos é atualizado a div para que novos comentários apareçam automaticamente sem a necessidade de *refresh*. Está funcionando corretamente:

```
setTimeout(listComment, 3000);
$("#output").html(list);
```

Até onde isso interfere no tráfego do servidor e se existe alguma outra solução para isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa trabalhar com [WebSocket](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) ao invés de ficar fazendo requisições. Hoje em dia existe diversas libs para qualquer linguagem backend que te auxiliam e facilitam a implementação. Veja uma lista com algumas linguagens `(caso nenhuma seja a que você está usando, comenta que eu atualizo)`:

- [Socket.io (NojeJS)](https://socket.io/)
- [WebSockets (Java)](https://www.devmedia.com.br/java-websockets-introducao/30443)
- [Ratchet - PHP Websocket (PHP)](http://socketo.me/docs/deploy)
- [Websocket-Sharp (C#)](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp)

Você também pode querer dar uma olhada no funcionamento do [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?hl=pt-br), que é uma solução backend tanto para mobile quanto web.

Comment: Olá Guilherme. Vamos usar o PHP. Vou dar uma olhada nos links informados.

Answer (score 12):

Interfere muito, de forma geral isto não deve ser feito. Você precisa de um [sistema de eventos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80611/101) (o mecanismo é este, mas a arquitetura para cliente/servidor é diferente).

Usando o Princípio de Hollywood o cliente se registra no servidor dizendo em que contexto está e o que deseja ser notificado, então o servidor manda algo para o cliente quando uma mudança relevante para aquele assinante aconteceu.

O sistema de atualização só é interessante quando quase todas as requisições trarão novas informações relevantes.

Hoje costuma-se usar [programação reativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225324/101) que eleva o sistema de eventos a outro patamar. Tem muita coisa pronta para fazer o *push notification*. Por exemplo, em C# costuma-se usar [ASP.NET SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Mas tem [outras opções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64234/101).

Para tem algumas, como [para PHP](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php) (não sei se é boa) ou [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/).

Tem serviços de API que fazem isto, mas parece que não é o que deseja.

Mas a ideia básica é usar [Web Sockets](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46839/101). A técnica costuma ser a de [*long polling*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254506/101). Procure também por notificação assíncrona.

Lidar com Web Sockets direto pode ser bem chato e e é fácil fazer errado, eu não perderia tempo, a não ser que eu quisesse ir fundo nisso. Prefira uma solução mais pronta.

É assim que este site, o Facebook, e diversos outros trabalham.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Olá Maniero. No nosso caso iremos usar PHP.

Comment: @Fox.11 dei uma melhorada